# Why does Spring Boot not configure Spring Session Redis?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

Following this [example here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-redis.html) I upgraded my Spring Boot 3.2 application to use Redis as session storage.

I've added the required dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I've set some application properties (yaml):

```yaml
spring.session.redis.flush-mode: on_save
spring.session.redis.namespace: "spring:session"

spring.data.redis.host: "localhost"
spring.data.redis.port: 6379
```

And I have a Redis server running which is connectable on "127.0.0.1:6379". I can add keys via `redis-cli` so I know, Redis is ok.

However, when I search the Redis database I won't get any keys related to Spring Session. Since authentication works I assume that the sessions are still managed by Tomcat itself.

According to the [Spring Session Configuration Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-redis.html#boot-spring-configuration) there should be a `springSessionRepositoryFilter` bean created, but this bean is not configured. Also, there is no `RedisConnectionFactory` in the context.

FYI: When using `spring-session-jdbc` instead the sessions are stored inside the JDBC database as expected.

Does anybody know why Spring Session won't set up Redis for storage although I followed the documentation step by step? Do I need to add some additional configurations which aren't mentioned in the documentation?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"spring-session-data-redis" need to use the redis client such as Lettuce. It's dependency paths to client are as follows:

`spring-session-data-redis`->`spring-data-redis`->`lettuce-core(<optional>true</optional>)`.

Maven will not auto import lettuce when you add `spring-session-data-redis`, since the optional is true. You need to add `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` or `lettuce-core` in your pom.xml.

Comment: Thank you for this information. In my opinion something this relevant should be part af an example within the corresponding documentation. At least it should be mentioned somewhere and not being left to the developer to find out in mysterious ways.

Comment: @Slevin You are right. I also spend hours to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

So after more than one hour spending valuable time in figuring out what the problem could be, I found in a youtube video the following dependency added rather casually:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Well, since the dependency to this package is never mentioned in the Spring Boot documentations anywhere, I wonder: are developers supposed to be crystall ball eyed fortune tellers in their second job? How the fuck shall I know that this is a major required dependency?

If you'd sum up all the senseless hours spent by developers figuring out how to get things working just because the docs are crap, I think you'd get to millions a month. Nothing more to say...